# How can I hightlight markdown in doxygen under vim?

Tags: vim, markdown, doxygen

The newer version of doxygen comes with markdown support. Is there an easy way to add markdown syntax highlight to a doxygen comment block in vim?

On a side note, one can add doxygen syntax to a `c` file by using `set filetype=c.doxygen`

Answer (score 2):

To do this right, the Doxygen syntax extension script would need to be extended to support Markdown syntax, either by duplicating the syntax, or by defining regions that can include Markdown and using `:syntax include syntax/markdown.vim` to include the syntax. Please contact the syntax plugin's owner with such a request, or even send a patch.

For a pragmatic approach that you can immediately use, my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) provides a command that can highlight certain ranges with a different syntax:

```
:3,11SyntaxInclude markdown
```

With this (possibly aided by a custom mapping to make this faster), you can highlight Doxygen-Markdown ranges on demand (e.g. when the text markup is so complex that you would have the comfort of proper syntax highlighting).

Comment: I like the `syntax include` alternative. I tried to do `syn include @markdown $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim` followed by `syn region doxygenBody contained ... contains=...,@markdown` but it didn't work; am I missing something?

Comment: No, the general approach looks right. Ensure that the `doxygenBody` region actually matches, a plugin like SyntaxAttr.vim helps with that.